# good architecture for quartz based email processor

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I need to write a windows service to send emails.  The emails will likely be stored in a database table and they should be sent as early as convenient.  It would be advantages to have multiple threads sending messages as there will be hurts at certain times of the day however it is not good to send the same message multiple times.

So I'm having a little bit of trouble understanding in this kind of scenario how I can best leverage quartz.net to alleviate some of queueing and concurrency issues.  So my architecture questions are:
1.  For this kind of scenario, is it best for a Job to check if there are emails to send or should a job be to actually send one email?
2.  If the answer to 1) is to check for emails to be sent then that would leave me with a concurrency issue and I would need to use DisallowConcurrentExecution which would result in only 1 email being sent at a time?
3.  If there answer to 1) is send a single email then I take it the job details would need to reflect the specific ID of the email to be sent?
4.  In either case - two web users could trigger the creation of the same email job (concurrently).   So it doesn't seem that Quartz really helps solve my problem - it might provide a nice architecture for a unit of work and controlling polling frequency but not really the core of my problem?  Or am I mssing / over thinking something?

Finally, just to be clear, each email relates to a specific Order so there is ID and state potential.  So because two web users can send the same email at the same instant in time should not result in two emails being sent.

Look forward to any advice.
Thanks
Josh

Answer (score 0):

Quartz.Net would meet your scheduling needs.

However, you have conflicting needs.  You want "more than one thread" to send the emails, but you also want "Do not want duplicate emails".

The DisallowConcurrentExecution will prevent multiple instances of the same job running at the same time.  However, if you have only one instance of the job running, you don't know which individuals emails have been sent or not sent.

If you only keep "these emails have been sent, and these haven't" in memory.....you're always at risk of sending duplicates.

You can solve this, but you're gonna have to have a "pessimistic" flag on which emails have already been sent.  Like at the database level.

So if you want multiple threads to send emails...that's ok.  But your "get some emails to send" code is going to have to 'mark' the emails it is working on.  (So the next thread doesn't get them).  Then you have to mark them again right after they are sent.

Quartz is good for scheduling the "when" your jobs run.  But it doesn't have the ability to "track" which emails you need to send and which ones have already been sent.  That's gonna be your responsibility.

I had this similar problem....where I had many many users trying to "get at" a bunch of to-do items.  Thus why I wrote this blog entry for Sql Server.  I needed to "mark" the rows, but also had to order them before I marked them.

http://granadacoder.wordpress.com/2009/07/06/update-top-n-order-by-example/

I also added some "hints".......

```
WITH ( UPDLOCK, READPAST , ROWLOCK ) –<<Optional Hints
```

because so many different users were trying to "get-at" the items.

(Think about how T1cket M@ster has to work.......there has to be some pessimistic locking on the tickets....and they have a timer that releases the locks if you don't buy the tickets in time).

Hope that helps.